# Javascript: adding content with animation after load

Tags: jquery, ajax, animation

I am using `jQuery.load` to reload a specific part of the page after a form submitting.The problem is that it add content to my website, but abruptly. I'd like something with some animations. It would be great if the new content popped or was revealed from top to bottom.

Here is what i've done so far : http://jsfiddle.net/9Dubr/651/

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var old = $('p').html();
    $('p').replaceWith('<p>.../p>'); // Emulates load
    var $new = $('p').html();
    var newh = $('p').height();
    $('p').html(old);
    $('p').animate({height: newh}, 500, function(){
        $('p').html($new)
    });
}, 1000);
```

But it is not what I want since the text appears suddenly

My load call :

```
$.reloadSection = function (id) {
  var q = window.location.pathname + (window.location.search || "") + " " + id;
  console.log(q)
  $(id).load(q, function () {});
}
```

Comment: Add text in the div before starting your animation. Have a look here for more effects : http://jqueryui.com/effect/

Comment: @sdespont thanks but I'd need to add jqueryui...

Answer (score 0):

when you insert new content it is per default shown with full height, you need to set it to 0 preor to inserting:

```
$(old).replaceWidth($(new).hide());
```

should do the trick

also use `slideDown` instead of animating the height yourself

Comment: Thank you but could you post a jsfiddle please. **And i cannot remove `$('p').replaceWith('<p>.../p>');`** since it is like `jQuery.load`

Comment: @Vinz243 you can use `$.get` or `$.ajax`, also `load` retuns immidiately not waiting till the content been placed so yeah

Comment: @Vinz243 parse what? `$.get("/api",function(d){$res.html(d);});` works perfecly fine

Comment: I am only loading a section (ie `.comments-list`...). see edit